# How to turn pandas df into 2D form

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd


input = {"Product" : ["Car", "", "", "House", "", "", ""], "Name" : ["Wheel", "Glass", "Seat", "Glass", "Roof", "Door", "Kitchen"],
         "Price" : [5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 4, 12]}


df_input = pd.DataFrame(input)
```

I would like to turn this df into 2D form. How can I do this please?

Desired output is:

```py
output = {"Product" : [ "Car", "House"] , "Wheel" : [ 5, 0], "Glass" : [ 3, 2],"Seat" : [ 4, 0],"Roof" : [ 0, 6], "Door" : [ 0, 4], "Kitchen" : [ 0, 12]}

df_output = pd.DataFrame(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), you first need to pre-process the "Product" column:

```
(df_input
 .assign(Product=df_input['Product'].where(df_input['Product'].ne('')).ffill())
 .pivot_table(index='Product', columns='Name', values='Price', fill_value=0)
 .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
  Product  Door  Glass  Kitchen  Roof  Seat  Wheel
0     Car     0      3        0     0     4      5
1   House     4      2       12     6     0      0
```